# Get data from product page and back Scraper

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
class Crawler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pag = 1
        i = 0

    def get_urls(self,main_url):
        self.url = 'https://www.test.ro/search/'+ main_url +'/p1'
        self.filename = main_url
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        number_pages = soup.find(class_= 'row' )
        last_page = number_pages.find_all('a')[len(number_pages.find_all('a'))-2].get("data-page")
        for i in range(1, int(last_page)+1):
            url.append('https://www.test.ro/search/'+ main_url +'/p' + str(i))
    def print_urls(self):
        for urls in url:
            print (urls)

    def scrape(self,url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        product_list = soup.find(class_ = 'page-container')
        product_list_name = product_list.find_all('h2')
        product_list_oldprice = product_list.find_all(class_ = 'product-old-price')
        product_list_newprice = product_list.find_all(class_ = 'product-new-price')
        for i in range(0, len(product_list_name)):
            name = product_list_name[i].get_text().strip()
            link = product_list_name[i].find('a').get('href')
            #print(name)
            #print(len(name))
            try:
                price = product_list_oldprice[i].contents[0].get_text()
                price = price[:-6]
                #print(price)
            except IndexError:
                #print("no old price")
   
            #print(product_list_newprice[i].contents[0])
            with open(self.filename+'.csv', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
                file_is_empty = os.stat(self.filename+'.csv').st_size == 0
                fieldname = ['name','link', 'price_old', 'price_actualy']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldname)
                if file_is_empty:
                    writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow({'name':name,'link':link, 'price_old':price, 'price_actualy':product_list_newprice[i].contents[0]})
if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Search for product: ")
    urlsearch = input()
    starttime = time.time()
    scraper = Crawler()
    scraper.get_urls(urlsearch)
    scraper.print_urls()
    #scraper.scrape(url[0])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(scraper.scrape,url)
    pool.close()
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

So I have this **scraper**, it works perfectly on any website bag but only on the product page.
I did it for a specific website, but how could I go on each page to take the data from the product and give it back and do it all over again?
Is such a thing possible?
I now take the data from the products page, ie name, link, price.
You have divs there too.
Can I help href?

Comment: FYI 'scrapper' (and 'scrap') means throwing away like rubbish. The correct terms are __scraper__ and __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to create a category scraper that safes all product urls first. Scrape all urls and go through all the category's and for example safe them to csv first (the product urls). Then you can take all the product urls from the CSV and loop through all of them.

Comment: I can not put all links from csv in array and scrap all data from links?